# C++ Qt Segmentation fault when trying to access method of an object

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, segmentation-fault, cross-platform

I am learning Qt, and I have come up with a problem. I would like some help, here as I tried changing variables and debugging it, but haven't come up with a solution. I'll provide some code to understand the problem i have

In my ColorButton.h class file

```
class ColorButton : public QToolButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
 public:
   explicit ColorButton(const QColor &color, QWidget *parent = 0);
   void testMethod();
};
```

My ColorButton.cpp file is like this

```
ColorButton::ColorButton(const QColor &color, QWidget *parent)
{
    //some code
}

void ColorButton::testMethod()
{
   //This is
   //a test method
}
```

I am trying to access this testMethod() from another class.

From this class, header file is Toolbar.h

```
class ToolBar : public QToolBar
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ToolBar(const QMap<ToolsEnum, QAction*> &actionMap, QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    void setToolbar(); //initialize items
    ColorButton *test; //-----

public slots:
    void setMainColorView();
}
```

The Toolbar.cpp file is like this

```
ToolBar::ToolBar(const QMap<ToolsEnum, QAction *> &actionMap, QWidget *parent) :
QToolBar(tr("Tools"),parent), actionMapVar(actionMap)
{
    setToolbar();
}

void ToolBar::setToolbar()
{
  test = new ColorButton(QColor("#8C001A"));
}

void ToolBar::setMainColorView()
{
 test->testMethod();
}
}
```

The program works when i put test->testMethod(); into setToolbar() , but I want **to create the object in setToolbar()** and call the **method in setMainColorView().**

So far I have tried making the Color button variable public, 
I have also tried initializing the object called test in the constructor, but both don't work.

Right now, with this code the error I get is
"The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.
Signal name: SIGSEGV
Signal meaning: Segmentation fault" 
with an arrow pointing at test->testMethod(). I have no clue how to solve it, any help would be appreciated

Comment: When is setMainColorView() being called?  Are you certain test is initialized at that point?  If you're using Qt Creator, run the debugger with breakpoints on where you initialise test and where you use it.  make sure it's initialised first, and when it hits the breakpoint on using it, examine it ot make sure it's a valid object.

Comment: @Ninjammer setMainColorView() is called from another class. I am trying to use the existing test Object that is created in setToolbar, instead of creating another object

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, and that's why I suggested using the debugger with breakpoints so you can check that things are happening in the order you expect, and examine the object you're trying to use.  Even without breakpoints, if you run it through the debugger and it segfaults on using the test object, you can see at that point if test is null, or if something in testMethod() is going wrong.

Comment: @Ninjammer got it, ill check it again and get back to you.

Comment: @Ninjammer okay i checked it, and the program works in the proper order, until I come to test->testMethod(); It's where I get the segmentation error. What I am trying to do is access the test object that is already created in setToolbar(), without passing the object into setMainColorView(). 

Like is there a way to make the test object accessible to all the methods in the Toolbar class.

Comment: It's public, so it should be.  What does the debugger tell you about test?  does it have a value of 0?  It implies that at runtime there's something wrong with the test object.  If it was an issue with the testMethod() not being accessible, you'd find that out at compile time.

Comment: @Ninjammer Sorry for the late reply, so far what I have tried is. I moved the test = new ColorButton(QColor("#8C001A")); to setMainColorView() and I still seem to be getting the same problem,
I also added the setMainColorView in the header file, in the code above, i forgot to add it before.

Comment: @Ninjammer thanks for all your help. I am sorry it was my fault. I was looking at the wrong place the entire time. I solved this by passing my toolbar object into the class i was calling setMainColorView() from. In that class i made a local variable of the toolbar object, assigned this. And then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the wrong place the entire time. I solved this by passing my toolbar object into the class i was calling setMainColorView() from. In that class i made a local variable of the toolbar object, assigned this. And then it worked.